# How to host a .NET Core 3.1 API web application as windows service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an existing .NET Core 3.1 API web application which I'd like to host as a windows service.
What is the best way to achieve this?

I've found several tutorials stating that adding the nuget package `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices` and using the `UseWindowsService()` function should be enough to host it as windows service.
This doesn't work for me. I'll get Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

I've also read about worker services but I have no idea how this would work with an existing API project.

My Program.cs looks like this:

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
                .Build();

            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseUrls(config.GetSection("Hosting:Url").Value);
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                }).UseWindowsService();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's easy if you use [Topshelf](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/09/27/creating-windows-services-in-net-core-part-2-the-topshelf-way/) It's even easier if you do it through other means (not c# specifically)

Answer (score 2):

I think that by downloading the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices` package, and then adding `UseWindowsService()` at the end of `CreateHostBuilder` in Program.cs, then publishing will be the easiest way. (It should be your current plan.)

> I'll get Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or
>   control request in a timely fashion.

As for the error you are currently encountering, please refer to [this document](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-timely-fashion/) to resolve.

You can publish your application completely by reading [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-host-asp-net-core-3-1-web-applications-as-windows-service/) and turn it into a windows service.(By reading this article, I successfully fulfilled your needs.)

**There are two points to note.**

When executing the cmd command, you need to right-click and select `Run as Administrator`, and then execute the sc command.

The executed command statement `binPath` and "=" can not have spaces, but the "=" and quotation marks must be separated, here is an example :

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc create MyService binPath= "C:\Projects\WindowsServiceDemo\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\win-x64\WindowsServiceDemo.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the 1053 error for .net core windows service, might be of help to others:

if the path to **appsettings.json** (or other external config files relative to base directory) is not correct, you get 1053

three things, in my case, affected the base directory path:

1. the publish option **Produce single file** was checked
2. started as a service from Services.exe (the same app, when opened as a console, had no problem)
3. how you get the app base dir

For the third point, I don't remember exactly, especially since I found these things through trial and error, but the following code worked for me:

```
private static string GetBasePath()
{
    using var processModule = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule;
    return Path.GetDirectoryName(processModule?.FileName);
}
```

I'll try and test these things better when I have time and make it a little clearer

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices;

namespace App.Name.API
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsService();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

I use CreateWebHostBuilder instead of Create WebHostBuilder since im more used to it (and unsure of the difference between the two).